# How I can calculate a datetime using a day offest and fix its time into specific one at the same time?

Tags: php, datetime

In my case inside a table record I have 2 columns:

- day_offset
- time

And I want to calculate a datetime as follows:

1. Move the current time day_offset days to the past
2. And change the time into database

For example if the current datetime is `2023-01-12 12:00:00` and the:

1. day_offset is 1
2. time is 13:00:00

The calculated datetime/timestamp I want to be: `2023-01-11 13:00:00`.

How I can do using PHP?

I need to do using this way because the user can only provide this info and I need to calculate an expiration timestamp out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it is:

```php
$day_offset = 1;
$time='13:00:00'

$datetime = new Datetime();
$datetime->modify('-'.(int)$day_offset.' days');

$datetime = Datetime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datetime->format('Y-m-d').' '.$time);
```

What I do is to brake it into 2 parts:

1. Modifying the date using php's Datetime `modify`
2. Re-create a new datetime using string concatenation.

If time is not in String format can use:

```php
$day_offset = 1;
$time=[
 'hour'=>13,
 'minute'=>0,
 'seconds'=>0
]

$datetime = new Datetime();
$datetime->modify('-'.(int)$day_offset.' days');
$datetime->setTime($time['hour'],$time['minute'],$time['seconds'],0);
```

If using Carbon same think can happen as well:

```php
$day_offset = 1;
$time='13:00:00'

$datetime = new Carbon();
$datetime->modify('-'.(int)$day_offset.' days');

$datetime = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datetime->format('Y-m-d').' '.$time);
```

Ot time encoded as Integer

```php
$day_offset = 1;
$time=[
 'hour'=>13,
 'minute'=>0,
 'seconds'=>0
]

$datetime = new Carbon();
$datetime->modify('-'.(int)$day_offset.' days');
$datetime->setTime($time['hour'],$time['minute'],$time['seconds'],0);
```